# Remove/Purge program with all residuals

Tags: uninstall, maintenance

In my quest to fix a conflict with AirVPN client and AA 17.10, I have decided to uninstall Air and remove all residual files, threads, ect.

[DNS conflicts & no connect wifi VPN](https://askubuntu.com/questions/982906/dns-conflicts-no-connect-wifi-vpn)

Investigating the uninstall, I have come across this code

```
dpkg -l | grep '^rc' | awk '{print $2}' | xargs dpkg --purge
```

which runs after the command

```
apt-get --purge airvpn
```

These, when run together are as thorough as possible for removing all related files.

**Is this safe code for the uninstall project at hand?**

I will re-install Air once the residuals are removed as to not create conflicts.

Thanks for your comments and suggestions.

Comment: Please run `dpkg -l | grep '^rc' | awk '{print $2}'` and see what will be removed, and where did you get that code as it looks and smells of trouble?

Answer (score 3):

My friend, please use this:

```
sudo apt-get --purge airvpn
```

It is sufficient to remove all that you need to. This code `dpkg -l | grep '^rc' | awk '{print $2}' | xargs dpkg --purge` is going to get rid of a lot that isn't related to `airvpn`. I don't know where you got that code from but if you want to see what it removes run it this way:

```
dpkg -l | grep '^rc' | awk '{print $2}'
```

I don't think you want to run that command.

Comment: Thanks very much for informing me of the dangers of this command. I actually found it on the airvpn web forum, and my instincts were to get a second opinion, as the code seemed complex.